# Python 2: How can I edit each part of my set object?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a small problem with sets. So I have a **set** called **s**:

```
s = set(['Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Gmail'])
```

And i have a **list** called **l**:

```
l = ['Yahoo', 'Google', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Gmail']
```

How can I check what stuffs in set **s** are in my list **l**?

Also I have tried to do this but, Python give me an error:

```
TypeError: 'set' object does not support indexing
```

So if **set** object does not support indexing, how can I edit each part of my **set** object?

Thanks.

Comment: Would you please read http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#names-to-avoid before using `l` as a name?

Comment: @Misha Vayvala hey, i answered your question, but just curious , what gave u that error, can u give the code?

Comment: @tenstar: `s[0]` will give you that error. If you tried `for i in range(len(s)): s[i] in l` for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test for the intersection:

```
s.intersection(l)
```

Demo:

```
>>> s = set(['Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Gmail'])
>>> l = ['Yahoo', 'Google', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Gmail']
>>> s.intersection(l)
set(['Yahoo', 'Gmail'])
```

You could loop over your set too, with a `for` loop, but that would not be *nearly* as efficient.

Answer (score 1):

```
print s.intersection(l)
```

That was the more efficient way. In your case:

```
s = set(['Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Gmail'])
l = ['Yahoo', 'Google', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Gmail']
print s.intersect(l)
```

heres the less efficient way:

```
resset = []
for x in s:
    if x in l:
        resset.append(x)
print resset
```

PS. instead of declaring a set like this:

```
s = set(['Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Gmail'])
```

try this:

```
s = {'Facebook', 'Yahoo', 'Gmail'}
```

just to save some time :)

Comment: The `&` operator works *only* with sets on both sides (`TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'set' and 'list'`). It  certainly will not work *at all* if the list is the left-hand operand.

Comment: dunno, but its working in my comp. even with one set and a list, anyway, if it doesn't, i'll update my ans.

Comment: Are you certain `l` is a list and not a set in that case? I tested this again on 2.7 and 3.3 just now, I still get the `TypeError`. `.intersection()` takes any sequence, it is just the `&` operator that doesn't.

Comment: yes, i declared it like this: `['Yahoo', 'Google', 'MySpace', 'Apple', 'Gmail']`

Answer (score 0):

Why not just try this for yor first question

```
[x for x in s if x in l]
```

for the second question i did not understand what exactly you are trying to do but i think just a simple for loop with items can do the trick or you can use `iter(s)` or use `enumerate(s)`
if you necessarily need indexes (thought those won't be indexes)